# Two "Robertson-Walker observers," velocity of baseball as seen by second observer right before it's caught?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry

The spacetime metric of a spatially flat ($k = 0$) radiation dominated FLRW universe is given by$$ds^2 = -dT^2 + T[dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2].$$Consider two "Robertson-Walker observers," i.e., observers with $4$-velocity $(\partial/\partial T)^a$. At time $T = T_1$, the first observer throws a baseball toward the second with velocity $v_1$. The baseball is caught by the second observer at time $T = T_2$.

Now, I am wondering, what is the velocity, $v_2$, of the baseball as seen by the second observer just before it is caught?

Note that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the *physical velocities* of the baseball (as would be measured, e.g., by a "radar gun"), not a "coordinate speed" (such as "$dx/dT$"). We are not assuming here that $v_1$, $v_2 \ll c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout the question I will use $p(T_1)$ and $p(T_2)$ to denote the 4-momentum of the baseball at times $T_1$ and $T_2$, $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ to represent the spatial component of its physical velocity, and $a(T_1)$ and $a(T_2)$ to represent the scale factor of the Universe at these times.

The homogeneity and isotropy of the Universe mean that no matter what direction the baseball is thrown in *by a comoving observer*, it will follow a geodesic in FRW spacetime, which is a 'radial' trajectory in the sense that

\begin{equation}
ds^2 = -dT^2 + a^2(T) \: d\chi^2,
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\dot{p}_{\chi} = 0,
\end{equation}

where $\chi$ is the FRW radial co-ordinate such that $d\chi = dr/\sqrt{1-Kr^2}$ for comoving curvature $K$, and $p_{\chi}$ is the component of the baseball's 4-momentum in this direction. The dot denotes the derivative w.r.t. proper time.

Mathematically, this condition on $p_{\chi}$ can be seen by lowering indices on the geodesic equation $\dot{p}^a+\Gamma^a_{bc}p^bp^c=0$ and relabelling dummy indices to obtain

\begin{equation}
\dot{p}_a = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_a g_{bc})p^bp^c.
\end{equation}

Since the metric here is independent of $\chi$, we see that $p_{\chi}$ is constant along the geodesic.

**Intuitively,** *since the Universe is expanding away from every point, it is expanding away from observer 1 in all direction, so all directions correspond to throws along a radial trajectory.*

With this knowledge, we want to formulate the problem in terms of **covariant** components of the momentum, so we will use the appropriate line element for a massive baseball,

\begin{equation}
g^{\mu \nu}p_{\mu} p_{\nu} = -m^2 = -p_T^2(T_1) + \frac{1}{a^2(T_1)} p_{\chi}^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-m^2 = -p_T^2(T_2) + \frac{1}{a^2(T_2)} p_{\chi}^2.
\end{equation}

The mass is not low-velocity, so using the special-relativistic mass-shell condition $E^2 = m^2+|\mathbf{p}|^2$, we get

\begin{equation}
m^2 = p_T^2(T_1) - |\mathbf{p_1}^2|
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
m^2 = p_T^2(T_2) - |\mathbf{p_2}^2|.
\end{equation}

Substituting these $m^2$ into the line element, cancelling the $p_T^2$ and taking the ratio of the two equations then gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{|\mathbf{p_2}^2|}{|\mathbf{p_1}^2|} = \frac{a^2(T_1) p_{\chi}(T_2)}{a^2(T_2) p_{\chi}(T_1)}.
\end{equation}

But as previously discussed, the $p_{\chi}$ are conserved along the geodesic, and so they cancel! Finally, since the mass is conserved, we can write the spatial momenta in terms of the spatial velocities as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\gamma_1 |\mathbf{v}_1|}{\gamma_2 |\mathbf{v}_2|} = \frac{a(T_2)}{a(T_1)}.
\end{equation}

This gives $|\mathbf{v}_2|$ in terms of $|\mathbf{v}_1|$ as required.

This picture of the time-sliced Universe should help to visualise the situation. The red lines are the comoving observers, the blue line is the trajectory of the baseball, and the black arrows are the **spatial** components of the velocity of the baseball at times $T_1$ and $T_2$.

[image]

Comment: What is γ₁ and γ₂? I assume it is the Gamma-factor γₓ=1/√(1-vₓ²/c²)?

Comment: @СимонТыран yes that's right, they are the gamma factors at times $T_1$ and $T_2$, respectively.

Comment: if I get this right the kinetic energy of a particle with mass decreases with 1/a², while the energy of a photon only decreases with 1/a?

Comment: @СимонТыран Only if you are treating the particle as completely non-relativistic, with $E = p^2/2m$. Otherwise it just depends on the relationship between $E$ and $p$, which is $E \sim p$ for massless particles, but $E^2 = m^2 + p^2$ for massive relativistic particles.