# Measuring the growth of the Hubble sphere

Tags: cosmology

I have a question which I believe will greatly help my understanding of the Hubble sphere and what it means physically.

Say we have a flat ($k=0$) Universe with no dark energy ($\Lambda=0$) during the matter-dominated era such that the first Friedmann equation is

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\Big)^2 = \frac{8\pi G \rho_m}{3},
\end{equation}

where $\rho_m$ is the energy density of a **perfect fluid** and $a$ is the scale radius of the Universe.

If I send out a photon *today*, at time $t_0$ when the Hubble constant has value $H_0$ and the scale radius has value $a_0$, what is the maximum *physical* distance over which I can 'communicate' using this photon?

That is, if an observer at this distance sends me back a photon immediately after receiving my photon, what is the maximum *physical* distance between me and the observer which will allow their photon to reach me at some finite time?

It would also be great to have a comparison between this case and the case for an accelerating Universe, highlighting the major differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After answering several similar questions on Physics SE I have realised I can answer this question myself using the concepts of the [(comoving) Particle Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_horizon), the [(comoving) Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Cosmic_event_horizon) and the [Comoving Hubble Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_volume).

If I want to know the maximum distance I can communicate in an **any amount of future time,** then I should consider the Event Horizon, which gives the greatest comoving distance from which an observer at time $t_2$ can receive a signal emitted at time $t_1$, as

\begin{equation}
\chi_{\text{ev}} = \int^{t_2}_{t_1} \frac{dt}{a(t)}.
\end{equation}

This is the distance at which the rate of expansion of the emitter at $t_1$ is *just* under the speed of light $c$, so that the photon can $just$ 'outrun' the Universe's expansion at this point.

I must then equate this to the maximum comoving distance I can *send* a photon between times $t_0$ and $t_1$ which is given by the exactly analogous concept of the Particle Horizon

\begin{equation}
\chi_{\text{ph}} = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} \frac{dt}{a(t)},
\end{equation}

which gives the maximum comoving distance over which the observer at $t_1$ will be able to receive my photon. Completing the example for the *matter-dominated era* as in my question gives (cancelling multiplicative constants)

\begin{equation}
\int^{t_1}_{t_0} t^{-2/3} \; dt = \int^{t_2}_{t_1} t^{-2/3} \; dt
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\implies t_2^{1/3} = 2t_1^{1/3}-t_0^{1/3}.
\end{equation}

Assuming we know the time $t_0$ we sent out the original signal and the deadline $t_2$ by which we want to get it back, we can then calculate $t_1$ and hence the comoving distance $\chi_{ph}$ to which we may send the signal.

**Accelerating Universe:** In the above example for the MD era (and in fact also for the RD era) we can put $t_2 \rightarrow \infty$ and see that given an **infinite amount of future time** we could communicate to any distance. But in an accelerating Universe there is *a finite limit even when we have infinite time* as I mentioned at the end of my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253183/two-robertson-walker-observers-at-what-time-will-a-light-signal-be-received/255902#255902). During the $\Lambda$-dominated era this would be given by

\begin{equation}
\int^{t_1}_{t_0} e^{-Ht} \; dt = \int^{\infty}_{t_1} e^{-Ht} \; dt
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\implies t_1 = t_0 + \ln{2},
\end{equation}

if we assume $H \sim$ const. (note that this is not a good assumption, but is included so I can solve analytically for illustrative purposes).

**Want to get the signal back within the next Hubble time:** In this case we should replace the Particle and Event Horizons by Comoving Hubble Spheres for me and the other observer. This is the distance over which comoving particles can travel *in the course of one Hubble time*.